# Upgrade Windows 8 Pro with Xampp to Win 10

Tags: xampp

How it will be after the upgrade? I have to migrate to Win 10 on a machine with Xampp. And I wonder what will happen with Xampp after the upgrade? Can someone give option is it possible to break something with Xampp, Mysql databases, Apache?

Comment: Not on topic for stackvoverflow. It may be on topic for another stackexchange site, however you need to be more specific about your questions with detail about your current setup and you need to look at the site FAQ to see if your question is a good fit. Broad questions such as "is it possible to break something with Xampp" are not good fit in general. What sort of things are you looking for? Any upgrade has option to break any given piece of software.

Comment: I see a lot of questions about Xampp here. I am sure my question is good to be kept here because this scenario has not been asked here.

Comment: Using Xampp yes, but this is about upgrading software and more of a system admin concern. There is a distinction and in any case you would need to update your question with details about your setup. These questions definitely depend on the type of upgrade you are doing, what version of Xampp, etc. Anytime you do any sort of upgrade there will be an opportunity for your programs to "break". Worse case is probably that you will need to upgrade everything to latest software (not entirely likely when going between 8 and 10 though).

Answer (score 0):

So I make the upgrade and everything is working as usual with Apache and Mysql. Case is done.